# autocomplete in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin

I have been using gvim for a while and now im trying eclipse and a feature that I really miss is the auto complete. Not just typing `pre` and getting `preg_replace` as a suggestion, but if I have a variable name that I have been using like `$_POST['confirm_delete']` then `confirm_delete` comes up as a suggestion if I type `con`.

Can I get this feature with `eclipse`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse (also Netbeans) cant auto complete array indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Eclipse does have autocomplete. But not for unknown array indices like `$_POST['myindex']`. Autocomplete works for all your normal variables and classes/methods.

Answer (score 1):

This might help : once you have already typed `confirm_delete` in your file somewhere, you can use eclipse's global autocomplete feature `Alt + /`. For example if you type `con` and `Alt + /` it will complete it with `confirm_delete` if it is the only word in the file that starts with "con" (otherwise type a few extra letters to be sure). 
This works everywhere in the file, even in comments.